# Simple hooking procedure

Tags: c++, dll, hook, code-injection

I'm trying to make a simple globalhook that prints some text into a .txt file whenever someone presses a key on the keyboard. The problem is that when I execute my program and press on a key in a certain program, the program gets stuck and doesn't respond anymore. So I think the problem is that the hookprocedure doesn't work/return properly when called.

this is the code in my .exe file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef bool (*install)();
install instal;
HINSTANCE hinst;

int main()
{
hinst = LoadLibrary(TEXT("injectdll.dll"));
if(!hinst)
{
printf("The DLL could not be found.\n");
}

instal = (install) GetProcAddress(hinst, "install");
if(!instal) 
{
    printf("The function was not found.\n");
}

if(!instal())
{
    printf("func couldn't be executed");
}

printf("Program successfully hooked.\nPress enter to unhook the function and stop the program.\n");
getchar();
}
```

this is the code in my dll:

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Strsafe.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma data_seg(".shared")
HHOOK hook = 0;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.shared,RWS")

HINSTANCE hinst;

LRESULT CALLBACK meconnect(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
if (code < 0) 
{
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
FILE *file;
fopen_s(&file, "function.txt", "a+");
fprintf(file, "Function keyboard_hook called.\n");
fclose(file);

return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool install() 
{ 
hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, (HOOKPROC) meconnect, hinst, 0);
return hook != NULL;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved) {

switch(Reason) {
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hinst = hDLL;
    break;
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;
}

return TRUE;
}
```

the meconnect function returns 0, I don't know if this is right, but I also tried returning: 
return CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wParam, lParam);
and
return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);

both didn't change anything in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `install` function runs in the context of your main exe. Make it return the `HHOOK` handle on success. You need that handle to call the [UnhookWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644993.aspx) function when you terminate your exe.

Alternatively, you could just store the `HHOOK`in a regular global variable in your DLL and implement an exported `uninstall` function, which will call `UnhookWindowsHookEx`.

Anyway, drop the shared section, which serves no purpose and can only bring problems.

Note that the [CallNextHookEx documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974.aspx) contains:

```
Parameters
   hhk [in, optional]
      Type: HHOOK
      This parameter is ignored.
```

Pass NULL as parameter 1 when calling `CallNextHookEx`

Always return the return value of `CallNextHookEx`in your Hook procedure.

do:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK meconnect(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (code >= 0) {
        FILE *file = 0;
        fopen_s(&file, "function.txt", "a+");
        if ( file ) {
            fprintf(file, "Function keyboard_hook called.\n");
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx( NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The DLL is loaded in the processes with keyboard activity. The text file is then opened in their "current directory". It may fail for access rights reasons, and you don't want text files sprayed anywhere : Use a valid full path for your text file.

Finally, **most important part**, if the thread that called `SetWindowsHookEx` doesn't have a polled message queue, things will turn weird (as you noticed). The simpler way of doing the right thing is just to call MessageBox.

Replace your `getchar` call by:

```
MessageBox(NULL, "Ok to leave", "Hooking Keyboard", MB_OK);
```

Your DLL will be loaded only in the processes with same bitness (32b or 64b). If your DLL is 32 bits, keyboard activity in 64 bits proesses is reported by an invocation of your Hook Procedure, **in the context** of your 32 bits EXE. This is the reason why you have to provide a polled message queue (it makes possible the callback call).

Edited: WH_KEYBOARD allows global AND multi-bitness hooking.

Comment: thank you so much! It works perfectly now, it was indeed getchar() that led to the freeze.

Comment: manuell, In general the detour works fine, but on certain programs I get a messagebox with the heading Werfault.exe - Application error saying: "The instruction at [hexadecimal] referenced memory at [other hexadecimal]. The memory couldn't be read". Do you have any idea what the origin of this error is & how I could resolve it?

Comment: One idea; Build a debug version of your Dll. Attach to the faulty process BEFORE you lauch your tool. Lauch your tool. You may be able to see the call stack and from where comes the crash.